# view is not loading using site-url in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-routing

i did everything to load a view from home page, but site url is not working here are the files 
view that i am loading is fundme-explore.php
in this i am using site url link in the explore tag

```
<div class="navv">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a class="navbar-brand" id="hm"  href = "<?php echo site_url('Welcome/explore') ?>">Explore</a></li>                             
   <li><a class="navbar-brand" id="br" href = "start_a_project.html" >Start a project</a></li>
   <li><a class="navbar-brand" id="ab" href = "About_Us.html" >About us </a>
   </li> 
</ul>
```

Here is my controller welcome.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

// Load url helper
$this->load->helper('url');
}
    public function index()
    {       

        $this->load->view('Fudme-home.php');



    }
        public function explore()
        {
            $this->load->view('fundme-explore');
        }

        }
?>
```

here is my route file

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;


$route['welcome/explore/'] = 'welcome/explore';
```

here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

and here is the picture of error i am getting

[this appear when load explore view from main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1DSx.png)

i did everthing what tutorials or in other guides mentioned still uable to detect whats wrong kindly help me if u know.

Comment: You can call view like this ` $this->load->view('Fudme-home')`

Comment: fundme-home is loading fine but explore view isnt loading, thats the problem.

Comment: take a look @the log file - because it looks like an PHP error or something (CI log under /application/logs/, php-errors Log and even Apache Log.

Comment: you should try like this way `<?php echo site_url('index.php/welcome/explore') ?>`

Comment: Tr some of these htaccess https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter you place the htaccess out side of the application folder. In the main directory.

Comment: Also in codeigniter you do not need to close the controller, models, libraries with `?>` explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change in your htaccess with following code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /YOUR_FOLDER/index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `application/config/config.php` make sure your ‘base_url’ config value is not empty. Typically this will be your base URL, with a trailing slash.

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://example.com/";
```

Also make sure that the file name starts with an uppercase letter. `welcome.php` should be `Welcome.php`.

Not part of your problem, but something you need to understand: You do not need and should delete the following route.

```
$route['welcome/explore/'] = 'welcome/explore';
```

There is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string and its corresponding controller and method following the pattern: `domain/controller/method`

The only time you need a `$route` is when you want to remap the relationship. [Read this](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#uri-routing) carefully for more detail.

Given the controller you show, the URL `http://example.com/welcome/explore/` will call the `explore` method of the `Welcome` class without any `$route` being set - assuming Codeigniter is correctly configured.